# Не запускаются файлы Ruby через FAR менеджер

Tags: ruby

Здравствуйте!
Установил с [сайта](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) версию `Ruby 2.4.2-2 (x64)`. Также установил с [сайта](https://www.farmanager.com/download.php?l=ru) `FAR менеджер`. Ruby установил на `C:\Ruby24-x64`. Создал файл `C:\Projects\MyApp1\app1.rb`  с одной строкой `puts "Hello"`
При вводе в FAR менеджере команды `ruby -v` или `ruby app1.rb` появляется сообщение:

> "ruby" не является внутренней или внешней командой или пакетным
>   файлом.

При вводе аналогичной команды в командной строке Windows файл выполняется ( Hello)
Как исправить ситуацию? FAR менеджер поставил впервые, потому, что делаю все как в [уроках](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQIZAw9MuYE) 
Прикладываю скрин[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте перегрузиться.

Comment: Спасибо, после перезагрузки все работает!

Comment: Тогда оформлю в виде ответа.

Comment: ОК, Я пока не понял, как здесь все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, инсталлятор Ruby прописывает свой каталог в переменную окружения `%PATH%`, чтобы при запуске ruby из командной строки его бинарники находились системой. Но значение этой переменной наследуется процессом из того процесса, который его запустил, и не обновляется само по себе. Поэтому нужна была перезагрузка, чтобы Explorer запустил Far с новым значением `%PATH%`.

Перезагрузите систему, всё должно заработать.

Comment: А если убить процесс explorer.exe и начать его заново -- не поможет?

Comment: @Nakilon: Ну это сурово :) Возможно, поможет даже просто перестартовать FAR. А может и нет. Но перезагрузка поможет точно.

Comment: @VladD не так уж сурово. В Windows 10 в диспетчере задач если выбрать среди процессов "Windows Explorer", кнопка завершения процесса поменяется на "Перезапустить"/"Restart". Довольно цивильный метод. Не надо набирать никаких команд.